# How to quantify or qualify the speed of a function could be learned?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, linear-algebra

In Gilbert Strang's book *Linear Algebra and Learning from Data*, there is a [sentence](http://math.mit.edu/%7Egs/learningfromdata/dsla_dlnn.pdf) said

> **Affine functions could be quickly learned**.

Why affine functions can be *quickly* learned?
How to quantify or qualify the *speed* of a function could be learned?

[image: dsla]

Comment: Maybe the idea is that an affine function can be learnt from a little data, while some other, say highly non-linear function might need much more data to be learnt.